# Selecting a MySQL row using a $_POST variable

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, xhtml

I am having some issues figuring out how to print the actual values from a row that contains the desired column value. I have two php files, quantity.php and quantity-inquiry.php, where quantity.php has a post submit form that redirects through quantity-inquiry.php to perform the actual sql.

quantity-inquiry opening php:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1) Connect to mysql database
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
include 'db-connect-99k.php';
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $databaseName);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
  die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2) Query database for data
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$searchName = $_POST['name'];
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name=$searchName");
```

$searchName is set appropriately from the $_POST (I can echo it out and it prints the correct input from the quantity form field):

```
<p> Product Name or PPI required (both not required) </p>
<p>--------------------------------------------------</p>
<form action="quantity_inquiry.php" method="post">
    Product Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
    PPI: <input type="text" name="ppi"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

In other words if I type "car" in the form field of quantity.php, $name in quantity-inquiry.php will echo out "car" as the $name variable. The problem I am having is that using $name as my query:

```
$searchName = $_POST['name'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name='".$searchName."'";
$res = $db->query($sql);
```

I can never seem to get the actual values. I have tried tons of stuff, for example:

```
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
    $rowName = $row['name'];
    $rowPPI = $row['ppi'];
    $rowQuantity = $row['quantity'];
    $rowPrice = $row['price'];
}
```

To set variables followed by

```
<tr>
  <td> $rowName </td>
  <td> $rowPPI </td>
  <td> $rowQuantity </td>
  <td> $rowPrice </td}
</tr>
```

Doesn't actually select a the field. For example, if I KNOW that I have 'product1' in my inventory table's 'name' column, and it is set as my '$searchName' it doesn't actually select it from the table and print it out as my $rowName, $rowPPI, $rowQuantity, and $rowPrice.

I have tried a number of other things that all end up in some sort of error or incorrect value being printed out. Is my query wrong or am I setting/using my variables incorrectly?

Comment: At a minimum, `WHERE name=$name` should probably be `WHERE name="$name"` (you need a better quoting solution, but that will get you started).  And then you probably also want to get the data out of your result, so something like `while($obj = $res->fetch_object()){ echo $obj->name; }`.

Comment: @bishop I have edited my code. I have tried it as, for example, $rowName = $row->name... as well, but I always end up getting the error on line 18. Also, I had to concat the variable name onto the end of the string in order to add it to the string like you were saying. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of this**

```
$searchName = $_POST['name'];
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name=$searchName");
```

**you should do this**

```
$searchName = $_POST['name'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name = ?";
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$searchName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $rowName = $row['name'];
        $rowPPI = $row['ppi'];
        $rowQuantity = $row['quantity'];
        $rowPrice = $row['price'];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$rowName?></td>
            <td><?=$rowPPI?></td>
            <td><?=$rowQuantity?></td>
            <td><?=$rowPrice?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    }

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}else die("Failed to prepare!");
```

**Or you can be super fancy and do this:**

```
$query = "SELECT name, pip, quantity, price FROM inventory WHERE name = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($rowName, $rowPPI, $rowQuantity, $rowPrice);


    while($stmt->fetch()){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$rowName?></td>
            <td><?=$rowPPI?></td>
            <td><?=$rowQuantity?></td>
            <td><?=$rowPrice?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}else die("Failed to prepare!");
```

Comment: Better solution than my simple one. Mine works but this is obviously much more in depth.

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks! Just a note: My solution protects your database from SQL Injections... The solution you posted still leaves room for SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

So I have just looked at the computer too long. Simple solution to a dumb mistake. I left

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name='".$searchName."'";
```

which is right, when I changed the following

```
$rowName -> $row['name'];
```

which was wrong. Then when trying to fix it I changed the $sql to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name=$searchName";
```

which was wrong, while changing my variable set to

```
$rowName = $row['name'];
```

So long story short if they were set as

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE name='".$searchName."'";
$rowName = $row['name'];
```

Note - all $row* variables should be set with = and not ->